# Limit to the number of variables-Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

I am building a web-application written in javascript and I am planning to use a lot of variables.So I was wondering if there is a limit to the number of variables i can have or if many variables increase the time needed for a page to load

Comment: Having tons of variables will decrease the speed of the application, but it would have to be a lot of variables for a noticeable performance hit. And I mean a *lot*.

Comment: Tons of variables suggest to me that maybe you should be using arrays or objects to store large amounts of data or fetching only the data you actually need from your server via ajax or breaking up a page into smaller pieces of functionality.

Comment: There is no limit, you are free to use as much as you want.

Comment: @AliAdravi - you will end up being limited by available memory on devices like phones.   The theoretical limit is probably related to the amount of virtual memory the underlying OS can handle, but the practical limit is real and will be related to how much RAM is available per page on the smallest device you want to run on.

Comment: @jfriend00 - he never mentioned that he want to use on device, and variable limit is totally different that the memory limit, a single variable with huge data will create the memory problem on device.

Comment: @AliAdravi - saying there is no limit is just simply wrong.  There is a practical limit for memory usage and coding like there is no such limit would be unwise.  Unlike you apparently, I assume that all web apps will be accessed via mobile devices (as should any smart web developer) and that questions about web development should consider all platforms they will likely be accessed from.

Comment: This discussion ignores that likelihood that the OP's "many variables" solution has a better solution. While it's true that memory exhaustion or some technical limitation of the size of the Javascript source code is technically the answer, I'd like to ask the OP - what problem are you trying to solve here? What about your application makes you want to create a boatload of variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables and their performance in javascript :

- Use local function variables (82% improvement, 63 microseconds).
- Avoid references to objects or object properties (41% improvement, 27.68 microseconds ).
- Avoid adding short strings to long strings (93% improvement, 4.608 microseconds ).
- Use buffering to process data in optimal sizes (96% improvement, 2.0 seconds ).

The above information is from the link below. Use the link for reference:

http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/jkm3/index.html.

It talks in brief about the performance and time taken by local variables in javascript .
Hope this will help you .

Comment: When was that article written? Without any date on their webpage, I have to assume it's outdated.